# Compile-time lookup from integer to type via C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to implement a compile-time type dictionary via C++ templates?
e.g. if I have a number of classes like these:

```
class ProtocolMajor1Minor2   { ... };
class ProtocolMajor4Minor3   { ... };
...
class ProtocolMajor12Minor21 { ... };
```

...is there a way to use C++ templates that would allow me to do something like this:

```
void foo(int majorVersion, int minorVersion)
{
    LookupMap<majorVersion,minorVersion>::innertype *specific = 
        new LookupMap<majorVersion,minorVersion>::innertype;
    return specific->FunctionalityFoo();
}
```

In case it is not clear, LookupMap acts just as the name says: given the two integer parameters (protocol major and minor versions) it is supposed to provide the specific protocol type I need, via the innerType "trait".

I can't use the preprocessor to create function "foo" as a macro (using ## or #), for two reasons: (a) it is big, not like in this example, and I don't want a huge function coded as a macro, and (b) the naming mappings are not direct (i.e. major version A and minor version B do not point to class "ProtocolMajorAMinorB".

You may also be thinking that "FunctionalityFoo" should be a member of a base type:
you are correct, but this is code generated from legacy code generators, i.e. untouchable. 
There are in fact many functions like "FunctionalityFoo" generated for each combination of (major,minor), and I don't want to create if/then/else ladders for each of them.

I tried template specialization but failed to find a syntax that works.

Is there a way to do it via templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, templates are compile-time construct, so you cannot use variables as template arguments.
For this to work you need to do something like this (i.e. not use runtime-provided variables):

```
template <int A, int B>
struct LookupMap { };

template <>
struct LookupMap<1, 2> { typedef Type1_2 innertype; };

// ...
template <int A, int B>
sometype foo() {
    typedef typename LookupMap<A, B>::innertype T;
    T* ptr = new T; // also, this leaks, use a smart pointer or something
    return ptr->something();
}

// when used
foo<1, 2>();
```

Comment: Which would unfortunately imply the if/else ladder for all the combinations of versions, right? When invoking foo, I mean.

Comment: @ttsiodras: Well, you can construct a runtime mapping, with e.g. `Boost.Assign`. But it would still need some writing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Boost.Assign - how would it help with the if/else ladder for all the combinations?

Comment: @ttsiodras: Something like `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, sometype(*)()> map; boost::assign::insert(map)(std::make_pair(1, 2), &foo<1, 2>)(...);` then the call-site is just `map[std::make_pair(A, B)]();` (with error-checking and stuff). Insertion could probably be made shorter with macros and maybe Boost.Preprocessor.